# How watch html elements collection and processed them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I on HTMl have:

```
<div id='mainPageNavigation'>
   <div><span id='home'><a href='#/'>1</a></span></div>
   <div><span id='faq'><a href="#/faq">2</a></span></div>
   <div><span id='contact'><a href="#/contact">3</a></span></div>
   <div><span id='registration'><a href='#/registration'>4</a></span></div>
   <div><span id='enter'><a href='#/enter'>5</a></span></div>
   <div><span id='page'><a href='#/page'>6</a></span></div>                                                
</div>
```

I need to watch on div#mainPageNavigation inner divs. If user make click on inner div -> add class on this div + remove class on other divs using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the case for which `watchesCollection` meant for. You can simply do this in jQuery. Try below snippet :

```
$("#mainPageNavigation > div > a").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().closest("div").addClass('test');
  $(this).parent().closest("div").siblings().removeClass('test');
})
```

Please make sure you're loading `jQuery.min` into your `DOM`.

Comment: I already do like this. But I am looking for code improvements)

Comment: There is another way you can make `directives` instead.

Comment: I used similar jquery code in directive - > watch scope variable. But it weary heavy.